# Comparison of characters in a string with a set of characters in C

Tags: c, string

I have been working on a project that requires validating characters in a string.

Say for example my set of valid characters is 'abcde' where all characters initiate different functions.

First, the code asks for user input. After, it gets compared to this set to check for any invalid input (any letters other than `abcde`). After this the characters initiate their respective functions.

I understand that it is possible to do this using:

```
    for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(string) - 1; i++) {
        if (string[i] != 'a' || string[i] != 'b' || string[i] != 'c' || 
            string[i] != 'd' || string[i] != 'e') {
            printf("Invalid Input");
        }
    }
```

The user can input three or four letters of any combination from the set.

Is there any simpler way to do this other than type out the entire condition in the if statement? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if(string[i] < 'a' || string[i] > 'e') { /* error */ }`
Also, do you mean to use `&&` in your if statement, rather than `||` ?

Comment: Search for the char in a static const array of valid chars, eg "abcde".

Comment: The for statement should be `size_t len = strlen(string) ; for(i=0; i < len; i++)` because `sizeof` will give you either 4 or 8 deending on how big a pointer is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*EDIT*: Thanks to a comment pointing out the standard `strspn()` function, which had dropped off my radar, we can implement it like this:

```
const size_t num_valid = strspn(string, "abcde");
if(string[num_valid] != '\0')
  printf("Invalid input: '%s'\n", string + num_valid);
```

This is nice since it pushes the loop out of the user's code, making it less complex.

Initially I claimed that this is a typical case for [`strchr()`]
(https://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr), and I still think it is:

```
for(size_t i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
  if(strchr("abcde", string[i]) == NULL)
  {
    printf("Invalid input: '%c'\n", string[i]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, silly errors. I rewrote it without indexing.

Comment: I'd provide the index driven one as well. We've got a 1 rep OP. The pointer version will blow their mind.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `strchr("abcde", *string)`?

Comment: @Groo OMG I suck. Sorry. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! For some reason the ++string gives me an error, what can I do to fix that?

Comment: @MananVora That's probably because `string` is an actual array in the local scope. I'll re-write again. :)

Comment: @unwind: I didn't have you down as a two space indenter. It was always my preference in my formative years, I think the bracing is easier to see with two spaces.

Comment: @BathshebaI Brace yourself: in real life I'm a physical tabs kind of guy, with the Linus-approved tab size of 8 most of the time. :) But I think 2 is enough here, for some reason.

Comment: There is actually a simpler solution: the problem is a typical use case for `strspn()`.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks!! I had totally forgotten, or perhaps never assimilated, that function.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could use the `strpbrk` function which does exactly what you need: find the first occurrence of any character, taken from a list of characters. Example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  const char STR_VALID[] = "abcde";
  char data[] = "invalid code";

  for(char* ptr=strpbrk(data, STR_VALID); ptr!=NULL; ptr=strpbrk(ptr+1, STR_VALID))
  {
    putc(*ptr, stdout);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
adcde
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it is pretty optimal to be honest, although you could consider using `strchr`. **Don't** be tempted to sacrifice portability by writing the ostensibly flashy `if(string[i] < 'a' || string[i] > 'e')`.

I have more issues with `sizeof(string) - 1`. If `string` has *decayed* into a pointer then `sizeof(string)` will not give you the number of elements. Furthermore `sizeof` returns an `unsigned` type, and the `-1` *could* push you through zero to the maximum `size_t` value!

Use a pre-computed `strlen` instead.

Comment: what would be the size around like if it was a pointer? just asking out of curiousity, how much would the size change?

Comment: @turmuka: If `string` is a pointer, then `sizeof(string)` is the same as `sizeof(char*)` which will be the size of a `char*` pointer type on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for your use case is a single call to the standard but seldom used library function `strspn()`:

```
size_t i = strspn(string, "abcde");
if (string[i] != '\0') {
    printf("Invalid input: '%c'\n", string[i]);
}
```

`strspn()` computes the number of characters at the start if `string` that match one of the characters in `"abcde"`. `i` is the offset of the first character that does not match any of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`. If it is not the end of the string, the input is invalid.

Note that the code in the question has some issues:

- the loop test `i <= sizeof(string) - 1` is error prone, if `string` is a pointer, `sizeof(string)` would be unrelated to the number of characters in the array it points to (if any), and if `string` is an array, `sizeof(string)` is the size of the array, not the number of characters plus one. Use this instead:

  ```
  for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
  ```
- you meant to use `&&` instead of `||`. The posted version always prints the first character of the string, unless it is empty.